# Cron Job consumers_runner has an error: Deprecated Functionality: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

Tags: magento2, cron, deprecated, php8

I have a store in Magento Cloud. There is particular job which is not working properly whenever CRON runs. Please check the error below,

> Cron Job consumers_runner has an error: Deprecated Functionality:
> trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is
> deprecated in /vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php on line 143.
> Statistics:
> {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":312475648,"emalloc_start":289127280}
> [] [] [2023-01-25T01:34:03.303651+00:00] report.CRITICAL: Exception:
> Deprecated Functionality: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1
> ($string) of type string is deprecated in
> /vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php on line 143 in
> /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

I have followed below article but could not find any proper solution,

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35380

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,